# I have managed to get data writing into Google Sheets but I would like to be able to 'overwrite' the data rather than 'insert_row'

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-sheets, beautifulsoup, gspread

The error I get when I try and do 'update_row' is the following:

AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'update_row'

Here is my code:

```
listing = soup.find_all('div', 'result-contain')
for details in listing:
title = details.find('h3')
if not title:
    continue
title = title.text.strip()[0:28]
price = details.find('div', 'price')
mileage = details.find_all('li')[0]
just_miles = mileage.text.split()
miles = just_miles[:-1]
adjusted_miles = str(miles)[1:-1]
adjusted_miles = adjusted_miles.replace("'", "")
link = details.find('a')

print(title, price.text, adjusted_miles, link['href'])
index = 2
row = [title,price.text,adjusted_miles,link['href']]
sheet1.insert_row(row,index)
```

Amy ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

**gspread** has no `update_row` method, you must be looking for [worksheet.update()](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=insert_row#gspread.models.Worksheet.update) method.

Tip: You could use python's `dir()` method to view all properties and methods of the specified object.

This example is from gspread worksheet object:

[image]

### Reference:

[gspread Documentation](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=insert_row#models)